# Get a list of filtered data extensions in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have some code in SSJS that retrieves all the Data Extensions (with most of its metadata)  in a BU.

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter)
```

Which gets a lot of information, but I want to know if a DE is filtered.

Is there some way to query if a given DE is a filtered DE (even if it's separate from the above call, that's fine)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no field on the data extension object mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html) which indicates that a data extension is filtered or no. If you follow any naming convention for filtered data extensions, that could help by putting a filter on the name column, but this object does not accept the 'LIKE' operator, so you have to first get all the data extension names in a separate Data extension and then filter on that using SQL.